# Problem with Print with timestamp and time format VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

for my school project I want to do a macro with excel vba which will generate a .sql script.

But I have issues with the Print function.

*1st :*  i have cells with time variables, it's formating as time cells **hh:mm:ss** but for exemple when I print this 02:28:0 I have this in result : 0,102777777777778

*2nd:* i have cells with timestamp variables, it's formating as custom cells with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss for exemple when I print this 2020-04-22 03:20:22 I have this in result : 27/08/2021 06:12:02. That means vba changes '-' for '/' and I don't want that.

Here is my code :`        Sheets("subscription").Activate

```
    nbre_colonnes = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    nbre_lignes = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 5 To nbre_lignes
        Print #1, "INSERT INTO subscription"
        Print #1, "VALUES( ";
        For j = 1 To nbre_colonnes
            If j = nbre_colonnes Then
                Print #1, Cells(i, j).Value;
            Else
                Print #1, Cells(i, j).Value & ",";
            End If
        Next j
        Print #1, ");"
    Next i`
```

Comment: Take a look at .Text rather than .Value..  Also research how to Format ranges in Excel.

Comment: .Text is more efficent than .Value for what i want, thanks a lot man. And i formated ranges by right click on cells. Do you want to post an answer that i will upvote and accepte as an answer ? And was my question was good ? i had a warning because of bad questions

Comment: You probably got a warning because the problem you were having is easily resolved by a little bit of research.  StackOverflow is supposed to be the 'Last Port of call', not the first place you go to if it doesn't work first time.  i.e. You came across as being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be resolved if you use the .Text method of Range rather than the .Value.  You should also research how to format cells so that .Text gives you the format you want.